# explode ("/", "///"); why 4 times and not 3 times

Tags: php, explode

I can not understand why when I run this code, it returns 4 times and not 3 times.

```
$pieces = explode("/", "///");

print_r ($pieces); //Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => [3] => )
```

Comment: Why it should be 3 times?

Comment: `explode("/", "1/2/3/4");`

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help. Indeed, if we put the text in, then we can see 4 values.. How tricky. Thanks Lloydpick and everyone.

Answer (score 6):

Think of `explode` as separating your string around your argument.

If you have an input of `///`, explode will split your string resulting in 4 outputs...

The 4 outputs are as follows...

`A/B/C/D`

```
$pieces = explode("/", "///");
print_r ($pieces); //Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => [3] => )
                              A      B      C      D
```

Answer (score 4):

The following figure should help:

```
_/_/_/_
```

How many underscores do you see? Four.

Answer (score 3):

Because there are 4 indentations, I will explain by example:
Write `///` as `_ / _ / _ / _` and see for yourself, so there are 4 elements.

Answer (score 2):

You are exploding on each side of the "/".

```
    $pieces = explode("/", "///");
```

This will produce 4 pieces. The "/" will always have a position on on each side.